Design pattern using fflib (Injector/Selector)
I'm working on a project that is using the fflib package. This is my first project using fflib and so far I'm really enjoying it, because it can do a lot of things and leaves a structure ready to be used.
One question I have is about the pattern used for mock/injector/selector. For example:
There are methods that will call the same selector multiple times:
List<Case> lstCases = ((CaseSelector)Injector.getInstance().instantiate(CaseSelector.class).functionA(paramA, paramB);
Map<Id, Case> mapCases = ((CaseSelector)Injector.getInstance().instantiate(CaseSelector.class).functionB(paramA, paramB, paramC);

Wouldn't it be more interesting to instantiate the selector class only once and leave the code cleaner and more intuitive? Follow the refactored example below:
CaseSelector selectorCase = ((CaseSelector)Injector.getInstance().instantiate(CaseSelector.class);

List<Case> lstCases = selectorCase.functionA(paramA, paramB);
Map<Id, Case> mapCases = selectorCase.functionB(paramA, paramB, paramC);

Or according to fflib's standard rules is it not good to do this?
I looked in the documentation, but I didn't find anything informing whether or not you can do something like that. Or I just wasn't paying attention.
